# Регулярное выражение: Не должно быть 9 идущих подряд цифр и первые 4 цифры не могут быть одинаковыми

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть следующий RegExp: `/^([0-9]){9}$/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5oVrRq/1/)

Он принимает только 9 цифр.

Как мне запретить ввести 9 идущих подряд цифр и чтобы первые 4 цифры не были одинаковыми?

Пробовал так: `(\d)\1{5}([0-9]){9}$`

Comment: `/^(?!012345678|123456789)(?!(\d)\1{3})\d{9}$/`? https://regex101.com/r/OdPfgy/1 Поясните, что вы подразумеваете под "9 идущих подряд цифр".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Все цифры одинаковые.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

```
/^(?!(\d)\1{3})\d{9}$/
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ljfbsN/1)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!(\d)\1{3})` - строка не должна начинаться с 4 однинаковых цифр
- `\d{9}` - 9 цифр
- `$` - конец строки.